# how to query LIST using linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Suppose if I add person class instance to list and then I need to query the list using linq.

```
List lst=new List();
lst.add(new person{ID=1,Name="jhon",salary=2500});
lst.add(new person{ID=2,Name="Sena",salary=1500});
lst.add(new person{ID=3,Name="Max",salary=5500});
lst.add(new person{ID=4,Name="Gen",salary=3500});
```

Now I want to query the above list with linq. Please guide me with sample code.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I would also suggest [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) as a convenient way to tackle with Linq for both advanced and beginners.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Does not directly answer the question with a sample of actual code (just a picture) - yes I know this is 10 years old but site standards also change

Answer (score 28):

Well, the code you've given is invalid to start with - `List` is a generic type, and it has an `Add` method instead of `add` etc.

But you could do something like:

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>
{
    new person{ID=1,Name="jhon",salary=2500},
    new person{ID=2,Name="Sena",salary=1500},
    new person{ID=3,Name="Max",salary=5500}.
    new person{ID=4,Name="Gen",salary=3500}
};

// The "Where" LINQ operator filters a sequence
var highEarners = list.Where(p => p.salary > 3000);

foreach (var person in highEarners)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

If you want to learn details of what all the LINQ operators do, and how they can be implemented in LINQ to Objects, you might be interested in my [Edulinq blog series](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/).

Comment: blog series link is not working any more , please update it or remove it .

Answer (score 9):

Since you haven't given any indication to *what* you want, here is a link to 101 LINQ samples that use all the different LINQ methods: [101 LINQ Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/try-samples/101-linq-samples/)

Also, you should really really really change your `List` into a strongly typed list (`List<T>`), properly define T, and add instances of T to your list. It will really make the queries much easier since you won't have to cast everything all the time.

Answer (score 9):

```
var persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person {ID = 1, Name = "jhon", Salary = 2500},
        new Person {ID = 2, Name = "Sena", Salary = 1500},
        new Person {ID = 3, Name = "Max", Salary = 5500},
        new Person {ID = 4, Name = "Gen", Salary = 3500}
    };

var acertainperson = persons.Where(p => p.Name == "jhon").First();
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} points",
    acertainperson.Name, acertainperson.Salary);

jhon: 2500 points

var doingprettywell = persons.Where(p => p.Salary > 2000);
            foreach (var person in doingprettywell)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} points",
                    person.Name, person.Salary);
            }

jhon: 2500 points
Max: 5500 points
Gen: 3500 points

        var astupidcalc = from p in persons
                          where p.ID > 2
                          select new
                                     {
                                         Name = p.Name,
                                         Bobos = p.Salary*p.ID,
                                         Bobotype = "bobos"
                                     };
        foreach (var person in astupidcalc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}",
                person.Name, person.Bobos, person.Bobotype);
        }

Max: 16500 bobos
Gen: 14000 bobos
```